# Firebase Functions Event Source stuck on pending

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-functions, event-sourcing, eventemitter

I'm trying to use an **event emitter** to trigger specific functions that I need.Here is the nodejs code.
Event source functions locally on **localhost** but once deployed, I cannot detect the event triggers. However, the logs on the firebase functions logger show the function being carried out. However, when tested, the function **does not provide any feedback to the event**

```js
const EventEmitter = require('events');

const Stream = new EventEmitter();

// 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
// 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE',

exports.eventEmitter = (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body);
    res.writeHead(200, {
        'Content-Type': 'text/event-stream',
        'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
        Connection: 'keep-alive'
    })

    Stream.on('push', function(event, data) {
        console.log('send0');
        res.write('event: ' + String(event) + '\n' + 'data:' + JSON.stringify(data) + '\n\n');
    });

    setInterval(() => {
        console.log('send1');
        Stream.emit('push', 'message', { msg: 'it works! hurraaay' });
    }, 5000);

}
```

When I **test this code locally** for event emission, using the following Angular code, The event is **detected and logged** on the console. However, once I deploy the function to **firebase functions**, I get a **pending request** on the network tab of the browser that doesn't have any log and seems to not complete at all and my angular code does inevitably detects nothing

```js
getStream() {
    return Observable.create(observer => {
      let url = 'link to emitter';
      let eventSource = new EventSource(url);

      eventSource.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
        console.log(e.data);
      }, false);
      
      eventSource.addEventListener('open', function(e) {
        // Connection was opened.
        console.log("open");
      }, false);
      
      eventSource.addEventListener('error', function(e) {
        if (eventSource.readyState == EventSource.CLOSED) {
          // Connection was closed.
          console.log("closed");
        }
      }, false);
      eventSource.addEventListener('message', message => { console.log(message.data); });

      eventSource.onmessage = (event) => {
        let json = JSON.parse(event.data);
        if (json !== undefined && json !== '') {
          this.zone.run(() => observer.next(json));
        }
      };

      eventSource.onerror = (error) => {
        if (eventSource.readyState === 0) {
          console.log('The stream has been closed by the server.');
          eventSource.close();
          observer.complete();
        } else {
          observer.error('EventSource error: ' + error);
        }
      }
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Cloud Functions HTTP endpoints do not support streaming data to clients like a websocket.  It can only receive an entire payload up front, then send an entire payload back to the client.  There are no chunked responses.  The limit for the payload is 10MB.  The default timeout for a function invocation is 60s and can only be increased to 9m max.  If you need streaming, then Cloud Functions is not the right product for your use case.

Comment: If I turn it to a web socket would it be viable??

Comment: And does AWS lambda work on similar parameters/principles?? What is a viable option??

Comment: I don't know - you should research your options.  Stack Overflow is not a place for getting product recommendations.

Comment: I got Server-Side Events to work on Cloud Functions, except that the events don't seem to get sent to the client as they occur.  When I run it locally, I get the events one at a time as they occur.  But after deploying to Cloud Functions, the server saves them all up and sends them all at once, when all the operations are complete.  Not super useful for getting progress updates on a long operation (my use case).

You might want to try long polling. I haven't tried it yet, but it's about the only thing that I haven't tried. WebSockets did not work at all on Cloud Functions.